# Bootstrap button groups with separators

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, bootstrap-4, border

How to get Bootstrap button groups with a border line separator between each button?

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">2</button>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/button-group

The @padaleiana solution is working fine! I used a btn-light disabled button as separator.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Workaround:

Create a button with `mr-0`, `ml-0`, `pl-0` and `pr-0` classes (margin and padding left and right = 0), and with `disabled` attribute (otherwise the "separator" will not appear!)

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-0 ml-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled></button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-0 ml-0 pr-0 pl-0" disabled></button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Somewhat surprising way, but the result is there! Thank you ;)

Comment: With Bootstrap 5, instead of, mr-0 ml-0, use ms-0 (margin start) and me-0 (margin end). Or even better, mx-0 (which set both ms and me). Same things for padding with px.

Comment: This works. However, it leads to issues with jQuery as it is a non-functioning button. button.js of jQuery 3.60 throws an error with this approach

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to padaleiana's answer is the following, which is not using HTML button tags. Thus, it avoids problems, when jQuery (or other Javascripts) iterates buttons:

```
<div class="alert alert-dark m-0 px-0"></div>
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">1</button>
  <div class="alert alert-dark m-0 px-0"></div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">2</button>
  <div class="alert alert-dark m-0 px-0"></div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It's a good alternative, great!